# Front-end and back-end

Tags: javascript, html, c++, css

Can someone explain to me how the front-end and back-end developing are meeting, or let's say consisting in the web development world? Is C++ a sufficient language for the back-end or I would still need to learn about ruby or python or C# or will it depend?

Comment: This question is so broad it needs half-a-book to answer

Comment: it does depend heavily on the scope and requirement specification.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you learn [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions and what we Expect from you. Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section clearly, and then, if you can, Edit your post to make t on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Font end implies direct presentation to or interaction with the user, such as through a GUI.

Back end suggests the software that's furthest away from end users, which is sometimes some kind of database or transaction processing engine.

You generally expect actions on the front end to be feeding into the back end processing - perhaps causing transactions to happen there, or starting reports running etc..  Sometimes events in the backend will lead to events in the front end, such as offering to display a report, or popping up a notification of some kind.

C++ is well suited to custom backend services needing 3GL languages, but sometimes features well beyond the scope of the C++ language Standard are needed, and it may be easier to get a proprietary database system, or an off-the-shelf solution to queue and distribute jobs across myriad hosts or otherwise "manage" things.  If could still be that some or all of the hands-on data processing is done in C++.